# Adding CSS to each individual element within a rails table loop

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have following tables in rails

```
<%= link_to 'New Voice', new_voice_path, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @voices.each do |voice| %>
        <tr class = "opinion-list">
          <td id = "opinion"><%= voice.opinion %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', voice, class: "crud" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_voice_path(voice), class: "crud" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', voice, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "crud" %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and it outputs this screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfUEv.jpg

How can I add CSS class to each of the voice so that each individual "voice" can have margin? Right now it looks too crowded and reads like one huge paragraph so I'd like to have some spacing between them.

I tried adding margin/padding to opinion-list but that doesn't work.

I've also tried using the content_tag like so

```
<%= link_to 'New Voice', new_voice_path, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @voices.each do |voice| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, class: "box") do%>
        <tr class = "opinion-list">
          <td id = "opinion"><%= voice.opinion %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', voice, class: "crud" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_voice_path(voice), class: "crud" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', voice, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "crud" %></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and style with the .box class but that also does not work.

Comment: If you want the margin to be uniform, can't you just put the styling on `tr.opnion-list { ... }` in your CSS? You might need to do `tr.opinion-list td { ... }` instead because CSS is funny about `tr`s, but is there a reason that won't work?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and tried .opinon-list td{ margin-bottom: 50px; }, but it still does not work

Comment: throw the !important tag on it and try again.

Comment: unfortunately margin-bottom: 50px !important; still does not work